# Help Identifying Component On Arcade PCB

Tags: pcb, identification, components

looking for help identifying a component that I think is damaged on this old PCB. It looks like a ceramic capacitor to me but I've been having trouble finding a matching one online. Could anyone help me identify the component and find a suitable replacement? I attached two pics, one shows the damaged component that I can't read any of the markings on and the other is of two very similar looking components on the board in good enough shape read the markings on it. Thanks in advance for the help! It looks to me to say '221J / 68' in case the images are hard to read!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it say 220p next to it?  It looks like the board helpfully has the component values silkscreened onto it.  The caps in your second picture have the value code 221, which is 220 picofarads.

Comment: Ceramic capacitor, 220pF

Comment: please examine the first picture ... the in-focus area is not where you are pointing

Comment: The first picture is out of focus, can't see the issue. Why do you think it is damaged component? As for the second picure, wow, Yamaha OPL2 chipset providing FM synthesis.

Comment: You can get full repair manuals and schematics for many classic arcade games for free online. For example http://www.retro-arcades.com/tech/boards/boards.aspx and many other places. That will tell you what the component is.

Comment: It does have '220p' etched in next to it, thank you all so much for the great info!